# How to solve the recurrence $a_{0}=1 , (n+1)a_{n+1}=a_{n}+(\frac{1}{n!}), n\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, algorithms, recurrence-relations

I know that I should got out the n!, since there is no root for it , if I multiply the both side by n! then it will become like :

$n! (n+1)a_{n+1}=a_{n}n!+1$

And then I have to put $b_n=a_n n!\ \ \ \  $ right ??

Any idea how could I get rid the (n+1) ??

Comment: You've forgot a $+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply each side by $n!$, then you get
$$
(n+1)!a_{n+1}=n!a_n+1
$$ or
$$
(n+1)!a_{n+1}-n!a_n=1
$$ which is straightforward to solve by [telescoping](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html).

Comment: how did (n+1) become factorial (n+1)!?

Comment: okay I think I understand .. (n+1)!= n!(n+1) right ??

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. By letting $b_n=a_n n!$ the recursion becomes $b_0=1$ and for $n\geq0$,
$$b_{n+1}=b_n+1.$$
Now find $b_n$ and then $a_n=\frac{b_n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 2):

I will write the equation as $a_{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}a_n+\frac1{(n+1)!}$.

The answer is $a_n=\frac{n+1}{n!}$. One can see this by induction. It is clearly true for $a_0$. Assume true for $a_n$. Then we have that

$a_{n+1}=\frac1{n+1}\frac{n+1}{n!}+\frac1{(n+1)!}$

writing this as a single fraction we have

$a_{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)!}$ and we're done.